# Deleting Model before View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

If I have this set of code:

```
[self.categoriesAndNuggets removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: indexToRemove withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

The program works fine.

But if I switch the lines,

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: indexToRemove withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.categoriesAndNuggets removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
```

everything breaks and the second line never gets called.

Happy to provide more code where necessary.

EDIT: My question is why is the program behaving this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error usually is

> "The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update, plus or minus the number of rows added or removed from
>   that section."

This mean that your data-source should reflect the table changes before reloading it.
In your first example you do:

1. delete element in data-source
2. reload the table, minus one element

While in the second one you do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Because The `-deletionRowAnimation` method will call the tableView view delegate method which is responsible for returning the UITableViewCell and the number of rows returning method

So if You reload tableView before deleting an item It will lead to crash